# LoadRunner recording Java Application launch from browser

Tags: loadrunner

Good afternoon,
I am trying to record a Java application which is launched from a web browser. I have tried to record as JavaHTTP but he application never launches.
Under Java recording the script is created and the application launches. During replay I receive 6 errors:

1. Error: search current JDK in Windows registry at(SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit)
2. Error: search in JAVA_HOME
3. Error: search in PATH
4. Error: JDK not found
5. Warning: Extension java-int.dll reports error -1 on call to function ExtPerThreadInitialize
6. Error: Vuser failed to initialize extension java_int.dll

I have installed the latest version of the JDK. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to resolve either script protocol to work? The system is running on Windows 10 Enterprise. I am trying to record in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to location of the JDK install directory.

```
Example: JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
```

OR you can go to `Runtime Settings -> Java VM` and set the home the Java home directory there.

If you are using 64 bit install then you need to set 64-bit replay
`Runtime Settings -> Miscellaneous` and click on Replay scrpit with 64-bit.

Also, be sure to include any Classes that you use in the Classpath.
Hope this helps, it worked for me.
Good luck.

Comment: hi bharat i also got above errors and i have followed below steps set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to location of the JDK install directory. Example: JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
OR you can go to Runtime Settings -> Java VM and set the home the Java home directory there. If you are using 64 bit install then you need to set 64-bit replay Runtime Settings -> Miscellaneous and click on Replay scrpit with 64-bit. but no use. i got same errors.here i can't understand how to include classes that are use in classpath.